# RPi and Motion sensor

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio

have been doing some basic GPIO projects, stepper motor, LEDs.
The Motion Sensor is giving me problems. My current code is quite basic, as basic as I could make it.

```
import RPi.GPIO as p
import time
p.setmode(p.BCM)

mpin = 18

p.setup(mpin, p.IN)

while True:
    if p.input(mpin):
        print("Detected")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

This will run and continuously return "Detected" even with the sensor completely covered. The bread board and sensor are correctly wired, as per an adafruit lesson.
Is the code correct? If not, how can I fix it to return "detected" only when something is actually detected? Could the problem be something physical? 
Thanks for the help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. After looking at the code, the board, the sensor itself, it was determined that the sensor module was built backwards of the standard. The code is fine, the wiring was (technically) fine. The sensor itself was faulty. Works now.